# Auth.signOut dosent sign out as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I am building my first app with AWS Amplify and React and I'm using withAuthenticator to force users to sign in. When I hit the sign out button it redirects back to the login page but if I refresh the page it logs back in and displays my app again, obviously, this isn't useful as I need it to completely sign the user out of my app and remove all their data from the browser. What am I doing wrong? I've even made a button to trigger Auth.signOut() but I'm still getting the same issue where I just can't log out from my app.

I've even used the global sign out here but it's still signing back in when I refresh the page.
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#sign-out

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './SE_logo.jpg';
import './App.css';
import Amplify, { API, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import {withAuthenticator} from 'aws-amplify-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';

async function onSignOutClick() {
  //await Auth.signOut()
  //    .then(data => console.log(data))
  //    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  console.log(Auth.signOut());
 }

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <button onClick={onSignOutClick}>Log Out</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of localStorage or cookies to persist the user's `authenticated` state?

Comment: I'm not sure I've only just started using Amplify and Authentication so I've left everything to the Amplify framework so presumably, it's storing the access token somewhere so when I refresh the app it finds them, knows they are still valid and goes straight into the app rather than prompting login again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the following code from my Apmlify.configure section, not sure what it does but I was there in the AWS docs so I left it in mine. I tried to delete all cookies and local storage content and it broke my sign in and just kept coming up with no current user so I found that removing the code below was the fix for that and its fixed my not signing out issue too?

```
      cookieStorage: {
      // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
          domain: '.mydomain.co.uk',
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
          path: '/',
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
          expires: 365,
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
      // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
          secure: true
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered `useAuthenticator` hook which has `signOut` function. I'm sharing it in hope that it'll help somebody:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './SE_logo.jpg';
import './App.css';
import { withAuthenticator, useAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';

function App() {
  const { signOut } = useAuthenticator()
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Log Out</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two options:

Wrap your app in a `<Authenticator.Provider>` component then use this hook call

```
const { signOut } = useAuthenticator();
```

or... wrap your app in a `<AmplifyProvider>` component and import the Auth component

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
...

Auth.signOut()
```

I haven't read enough of the documentation to know which is preferreed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redirect the user after logout like this

```js
async function handleLogout() {
  await Auth.signOut();

  userHasAuthenticated(false);

  history.push("/login");
}
```

You can use this tutorial to set up the browser history and redirect the user:
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html

Comment: all I get for this is userHasAuthenticated is not defined

Comment: you have to create a new state userHasAuthenticated to track user state, but you could also remove that line for now as the main goal is to redirect the user to the login screen

Comment: Redirecting to the login screen was never an issue when I call Auth.signOut it redirects back to the login screen, but then I click refresh or hit F5 it goes back into my app so basically logs back in automatically, I need it to fully log out as if a new person opened the browser and went to my site it would log in as the previous user.

Answer (score 0):

remove your localstorage data / cookies / ect 
or 
try this

```
async onSignOutClick() {
 await Auth.signOut()
     .then(data => console.log(data))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Nope, it redirects back to the sign-in page but if I press F5 it logs straight back into the app.

Comment: Can you provide the console.log of the auth.Signout request?

Comment: It returns a promise with a status of resolved and a value of undefined

Comment: Can you provide a sample pls?

Comment: I've added to my question :)

Comment: And the .then(data => console.log(data)

Comment: that just returns undefined

Comment: function App(props) { function signOut() { Auth.signOut() .then(() => { props.onStateChange('signedOut', null); }) .catch(err => { console.log('err: ', err) }) } return ( <View> <Text>Hello World</Text> <Text onPress={signOut}>Sign Out</Text> </View> ) } try this

Comment: I had to change the View to a div and the text to a h1, but it still has the same issue it redirects back to the login page as you'd expect but a refresh of the page or even closing the browser and reopening it and navigating to localhost:3000 and you go straight to the app not the sign in page.

Comment: Add a param to the navigate and if the param is present redirect?

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can do this....

```
signOut(){
    console.log('...signing out ....');
    Auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```